# How to inherit multiple instances of a class from a single class in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Disclaimer: I am new to programming and have just started learning about Classes and Inheritance so perhaps it is my lack of understanding which is causing me issues?

I have created two classes in seperate files `person.py` and `address.py`.

The person class inherits from the address class however a person can have multiple addresses (postal, physical etc..) How can I inherit multiple instances of my address class to for each type.

My goal is to eventually have a library of common classes for future projects so any help or constructive comments around this concept are much appreciated.

I want to be able to create something like the below code where both the postal and the physical address utilise the `Address` class:

```
employee = Person()
employee.set_postal_address("342 Gravelpit Terrace","Bedrock")
employee.set_physical_address("742 Evergreen Tce", "Springfield")
```

Below is my code, I have not created any reference to `Address()` in the `Person()` class as I am not sure how to achieve this?

```
# address.py

class Address:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__line1 = None
        self.__line2 = None
        self.__town_city = None
        self.__post_code = None
        self.__state_region = None
        self.__country = None

    # Line 1
    def get_line1(self):
        return self.__line1

    def set_line1(self, line1):
        self.__line1 = line1

    #etc....
```

```
# person.py

from address import * 

class Person(Address):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__first_name = None
        self.__last_name = None
        self.__postal_address = []
        self.__physical_adress = []


    def set_postal_address(self):
        # use the address class 
        # return a list of address values
        self.__postal_address = []

    def set_physical_address(self):
        # use the address class 
        # return a list of address values
        self.__physical_address = []  

    #etc...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  If there is a better way of handling this please let me know.

Comment: No need for inheritance. Also, getters and setters are largely considered unpythonic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply/response.
The reason I used `get` and `set` methods is because I have heard that it is not good practise to alter/call the variables outside of the class.  
Can you please let me know how I should be referring to these variables?

Comment: You can refer to them directly, I believe. Why the double underscores, by the way?

Comment: The double underscores was a way to make the variables private i.e. not accessible outside of the class.   This is why I needed to use `get` and `set` to access them. 
The reason I did this, is I have heard that I shouldn't access variables directly from outside of the class.

Comment: The double underscore prefix AFAIK is used to avoid accidentally accessing or overriding something in a subclass. The single underscore prefix is a convention meant to indicate that something is “private”. The only actual difference it makes is that names with a single leading underscore are not imported when you use an asterisk (`from some_module import *`), which you shouldn’t be using anyway. I wrote “private” in quotes because it’s more “this is for internal use, we don’t guarantee consistency, backwards compatibility or ease of use” than “this is a secret, you can’t access it”.

Comment: Of course there may be cases where it having getter/setter-esque methods makes sense. I just don’t think that’s the case here.

Comment: Here is a link to a great video on the subject: https://youtu.be/HTLu2DFOdTg?t=33m20s

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderCécile as I am a beginner, there is a high possibility I have understood this concept wrong.
After reading section 9.6 of the following website [https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html] it appears that you are correct? However, I am still trying to get my head around this concept. Thanks for your comments and video reference.

Comment: I will write up an answer, which should explain things more clearly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to necessarily inherit `Address` when creating the class `Person`. One way to achieve your goal is to initialize an `Address` class object within the `Person` class.

```
# address.py

class Address:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__line1 = kwargs.get('__line1')
        self.__line2 = kwargs.get('__line2')
        self.__town_city = kwargs.get('__town_city')
        self.__post_code = kwargs.get('__post_code')
        self.__state_region = kwargs.get('__state_region')
        self.__country = kwargs.get('__country')

    # Line 1
    def get_line1(self):
        return self.__line1

    def set_line1(self, line1):
        self.__line1 = line1

    #etc....
```

```
# person.py

from address import * 

class Person:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__first_name = kwargs.get('__first_name')
        self.__last_name = kwargs.get('__last_name')
        self.__postal_address = None
        self.__physical_address = None


    def set_postal_address(self, **kwargs):
        # use the address class 
        self.__postal_address = Address(**kwargs)

    def set_physical_address(self, **kwargs):
        # use the address class 
        self.__physical_address = Address(**kwargs)

    #etc...
```

This allows you to keep inherited methods from getting cluttered in a given class object but still allows you to keep nice class structures.

Then you can do something like:

```
bob=Person(__first_name='Bob', __last_name='Smith')
bob.set_postal_address(__line1='42 Wallaby Way', __town_city='Sydney')
# Since we are using kwargs.get() any not specified Kwarg comes out as None.
# Now `__postal_address` is its own Address class and comes with Address methods
bob.__postal_address.set__line2('Apt 3B')
```

Now there are times when you would want to inherit common methods from higher level classes. You can read more on python classes here: (https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Thanks @conmak for your answer. 
How would I use `set_postal_address()` ??

I have tried the following code;


`bob = Person()`
`bob.set_postal_address("123 Main Street", "Townsville")`

however I receive an error "Too many positional arguments for method call"

Comment: Yes that is my mistake. Edited the response to account for adding kwargs to the __init__ in Address.